# Credit memo "Return to Stock" not working properly, Configurable Product

Tags: magento2, magento-community, magento2.4, magento2.4.1

Here is my setup:
Magento 2.4.1

Stores->Configuration->Sales->Payment Methods->Braintree (sandbox)->Payment Action = "Intent Sale" (same as "Authorize and Capture")

Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Stock Options->"Decrease Stock When Order is Placed" = Yes

Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Product Stock Options->"Automatically Return Credit Memo Item to Stock" = No

Since all Payment Action is "Auth and Capture", the Orders are automatically Invoiced and Order Status is: "Processing"

1. Customer purchases a quantity of a Product Variation (a child product of the configurable product), in this case the remaining stock.
2. I issue a Credit Memo to Refund (either before Shipping or after Shipping, it doesn't matter), open the Invoice and click on "Credit Memo" at the top of the window, select "Return to Stock" for all line items.
   [image: Credit Memo screenshot]

The Quantity and Salable Quantity for each Simple Product Variation is NOT getting updated, they both show 0.
[image: Product Quantities after Credit Memo screenshot]

However, if I manually update product Quantity and Stock Status (to In Stock) for each Simple Product Variation - the Quantity is updated BUT the Salable Quantity/Default Stock now includes the Credited Stock so that the Quantity and Salable Quantity are way out of sync.
[image: Manually updated quantities screenshot]

Stock status is now all messed up - Salable Quantity / Default Stock is wrong!

It seems like neither the Inventory Reservation table or the product Stock Quantity are being updated properly when an order is returned to stock.

This seems like a serious bug...?

Evelyn

Answer (score 0):

2021-02-22 Edit:

I'm going to chalk this up to extension incompatibility.  I believe the extension I purchased to customize the Order, Invoice, Credit Memo, and Shipment numbers caused this issue.  It caused some exception errors in the backend when processing a shipment.  So I removed the Custom Order Number extension, and retested my order processing - now the Stock reservations, count updates, etc seem to be working correctly.